# How can I enable the word matching feature of the scrollbar in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In my Visual Studio 2015 installation when I click on a word in the editor all other occurrences of that word within the current file are highlighted and a small purpleish square appears in the scrollbar for each one.

In Visual Studio 2017 I don't get either of those features happening. I assume I have the feature turned off or am missing an optional extension. I don't know what the feature or option is called or if it is native Visual Studio or plugged in.

How can I enable this feature in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this. After I installed the Visual Studio extension called Productivity Power Tools 2017 the word matching feature appears.

The specific feature is called Match-Margin and it is available either as part of the Productivity Power Tools 2017 or individually:
[Productivity Power Tools 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017)
[Match Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MatchMargin/)